# Two floating divs, one right and one left. How do I force them to stay on one line?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

Alright, here's my problem: I've got a Div with a logo in it floated left, and a div with a menu in it floated right. When they touch, the menu drops to a new line, and I'd like them to be forced to stay on a single line, with the logo getting smaller instead.

```
|                                                                  |
|    +---------------+                                             |
|<---|      logo     |--->                                         |
|    | variable width|  +----------------------------------------+ |
|    |   float left  |  |                Menu                    | |
|    |               |  |    fixed width based on content        | |<----->
|    |               |  |             float right                | |
|    |               |  +----------------------------------------+ |
|    +---------------+                                             |
|                                                                  |
```

The layout is basically:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Logo">
        <a>
            <img></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="MenuContainer">
        <div class="MenuInnards"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The real question is what do you want it to do when the screen width is smaller than the width of the two divs combined?

Comment: @shelvacu That's not the real question at all.

Comment: @Charlie Why not? There are a few different ways of solving the problem, depending on how OP wants it to look. If they want it squished onto the page, then width percentages would likely be the best.

Comment: @shelvacu Whoops, read it as "why do you want." Sorry about that.

Comment: @shelvacu: I want the logo to shrink if the screen size gets too small. Logo attached to the left, menu attached to the right, and when they touch the logo needs to shrink instead of the menu getting shifted to a newline.

Comment: @Pixeltramp Then I believe you'll need to use javascript, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "display:table" to solve the problem. By using this code you can also vertically center the content (as you show in your scheme).

HTML

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Logo">
        <a>
            <img></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="MenuContainer">
        <div class="MenuInnards"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Container{max-width: 800px; width: 100%; display:table;}
.Logo{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
.Logo a img{width: 100%; max-width: 200px}
.MenuContainer{vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell; width:400px;}
.MenuInnards{float:right;}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]Try this

HTML

```
<div id="holder">
   <div id="left">
      <a><img/></a>
   </div>
   <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#holder {
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#left {
    width: 248px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#right {
    width: 640px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't answer my question whatsoever, as everything is fixed width and my question involves a responsive screen size.